# Where does windows update store BSOD dump files?

Tags: bsod

I'm trying to update a machine from 1703 to 20H2 and during the update process, it BSODs.

System scan at raised IRQL caught improper drier unload

I'd love to look at the dump file but nothing shows up in windows\Minidump

The BSOD happens after a restart while progress is counting up. This seems to put the dump files someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for folders.

The simplest method would be to use Windows Explorer and search for
`*.dmp`. The result will be sorted in descending date order,
so you can locate easily the file by date.

If no file is suitable, then the crash didn't generate a dump.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd love to look at the dump file but nothing shows up in
> windows\Minidump

Make sure you are set up to create minidumps.  Advanced System Settings.  Advanced Tab.  Startup and Recovery tab and make sure you have set for minidumps and what location System Root\ Memory.dmp

After making changes, you should, of course, restart the computer.

[image]